# How to parse date from database in iPhone

Tags: java, ios, datetime

I have a .db file that I retrieved from my iCloud account. I am trying to parse the date field from one of the tables. I'm doing this in Java. I'm not quite sure how it's stored because it seems like it's just a number.

I am taking taking this value and parsing it into a long which a pass to a Date object in java. However, it seems to always be sometime in January of 1970.

Value stored for date: 356898417 gives me 1970-01-04 when I call Date.toString

Comment: Please give the actual date which is stored in iCloud

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Date Constructor accepts one argument that equals the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970.

```
Date(long millisec)
```

Provide the actual datetime stored in the iCloud to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If that numeric value is given in seconds you need to multiply it by 1000 to make it milliseconds.

eg:

```
 String dateAsText = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                          .format(new Date(356898417 * 1000L));
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. They are stored in `Mac` absolute time `(seconds)`

```
long valueStoredInIphone = (something);
long millis = (valueStoredInIPhone * 1000) + 978307200000L;
Date dateSent = new Date(millis);
```

> http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.com/2012/10/whos-texting-ios6-smsdb.html